# PHP: How to read multidimensional array of sql?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to read and combine two arrays that has been selected in the database. So, below are the codes:

//declaration of the array

$datas = array();

```
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        { 
            $datas[]=$row['masa'];

            print_r($datas);


            if(in_array("Pagi",$datas)&&in_array("Petang",$datas))
            {
                echo"
                    <tr>
                    <td>Sudah ditempah </td>
                    <td>Sudah ditempah</td>
                    <td>Sudah ditempah</td>
                    </tr>";
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:
Array ( [0] => Pagi ) Array ( [0] => Pagi [1] => Petang )

So now, i want to combine these two arrays in order to perform the above action(as in the code).

Comment: It's already combined. Do `print_r()` outside your while loop to see the actual value of `$datas.`

Comment: if you intent is to echo that row once, just add a counter

Comment: @Mr.Blue. thank you fr your respond

Comment: How to add the counter? sorry because i'm a bit noob in php array